# ProcessRequest Called Repeatedly On Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

My question is, what causes System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) to be called?

I'm working on a project I did not write and I have identified the slowdown inherent with the application with ProcessRequest being called roughly ~1,200 times when Default.aspx is loaded.

It is definitely not being called manually anywhere in the code and I'm not sure what triggers it to keep being called.

EDIT: Here is a summary of what the profiler is showing me:

- WebDev.WebServer40.EXE (1539 samples)

  - asp.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(class System.Web.HttpContext) (1294 samples)

    - System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(class System.Web.HttpContext) (1294 samples)

Comment: Must be a custom HttpHandler

Comment: I triple checked the project and there is no custom HttpHandler.

Comment: If it's being called, you must be able to spot it on debugging mode.

Comment: Yes, profiling is how I identified the function causing the issue. The problem is, this function is invoked by IIS server process and not by the code. I'm curious as to what would cause the server to invoke ProcessRequest ~1200 times for a single page request.